# razor, asp.net add elements to a list with javascript but retrieve that list in controller

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am adding elements to a list inside the frontend in my razor page:

```
<button class="baseButton" style="width: 50% !important; background-color: black !important;" onclick="addLingua()">Sprache hinzufügen</button>
```

This button will fire this function:

```
function addLingua(){

            // the selection on the select
            var selected = $("#ourselect :selected");
            var radiomusthave = document.querySelector('input[name="yy"]:checked').value;
            var radioLanquality = document.querySelector('input[name="rr"]:checked').value;

            var radioMustHaveResult = ""

            if (radiomusthave == "MustHave") radioMustHaveResult = "Must have"
            else radioMustHaveResult = "Nice to have"


            if(selected.val() == '') {
                alert('Bitte wähle erst eine Sprache aus.')
                return; 
            }

            // Test to see if the browser supports the HTML template element by checking
            // for the presence of the template element's content attribute.

            if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) 
            {
                const clone = document.querySelector('#pickedLan').content.cloneNode(true);
                let p = clone.querySelectorAll("p");
                let button = clone.querySelectorAll("button");
                let mainDiv = clone.querySelectorAll(".findme");
                var idtodel = "#" + selected.val().trim()

                if ($(idtodel).length) {

                   alert('Bitte wähle eine noch nicht gewählte Sprache aus. Wenn du Änderungen vornehmen willst, dann kannst du die gewählte Sprache auch jederzeit neu löschen.')
                   return; 
                }

                p[0].innerHTML = selected.text()
                p[1].innerHTML = radioLanquality;
                p[2].innerHTML = radioMustHaveResult;

                // add id to main div to be deleteable
                mainDiv[0].id = selected.val().trim()

                // add button to delete
                button[0].addEventListener('click', () => {    
                    $(idtodel).remove()
                    counterOfElemensAdded--;
                    EnableOrDisbableButton();
                });

                document.querySelector("#pickedLingua").appendChild(clone);
            } 
            else 
            {
               // backup when unsupported
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = '<p id="' + selected.val() + '">' + selected.text() + '</p>';
                document.getElementById('pickedLingua').appendChild(div);
            }

            counterOfElemensAdded++;
            EnableOrDisbableButton()

        }
```

What basically happens is when the user clicks the button inside the frontend a list with attributes is created with more and more attributes the more the user clicks the button.

But when I now submit the page the controller has no idea over what items are on the list as it is a javascript list.

How can I add information to the controller over what items have been added to the list in the frontend and then submit the whole list to my backend when the page is submitted?